# Adobe AIR to iPhone stage size

Tags: iphone, air

I'm having trouble getting my head around the issue of stage size for an adobe AIR->iOS app.

I've read that you need to choose a particular screen size to design your assets for. Ok so that's straightforward, my target is the retina and portrait so I design them for 640x960. I'm also told that if you leave the settings as they are the resulting file will scale according to the device it's on, so 640x960 will scale down to 320x480, ok cool. What I don't get though is what happens with the stage size settings in the .fla. So for example if I leave it at 320x480, but my assets are all bigger (designed for 640x960) on the iphone4 will my stage size actually be 640x960? so in otherwords setting the stage size in the .fla doesn't make any difference anyway? and/or is it just really there for when you publish and test it on the desktop? or is it better to just set the stage to what I'm designing the assets for anyway (640x960) and everything will just be taken care of in the down scalling to older phones?

On top of all of that, is in my game I have a ball that bounces -10 pixels up when it hits something, at least it did when I was designing for 320x480, when I increased the stage size to 640x960, of course that -10 wasn't enough anymore, so I'm now going to double it to -20 pixels, but what will happen when the game is played on an older 320x480 device? is it still going to be bouncing at -20 pixels and just scalled down so it doesn't make any difference anyway? or what?

I'm trying to understand what's need to be scaled via coding i.e actual values needed to be scaled or if you don't need to do any of that because it just visually being displayed at a smaller resolution.

Ha, sorry bit confused here :p